# (Excel) Using IF function to check 2 cells for input and returning a value based on result

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am creating a spreadsheet to check the name of a person completing a job and to check if they updated the database upon completion.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E486.png

So if 'Alex' was to complete a job and update the database then return 1 to a cell. However if 'Alex' was to complete a job and not update the database then return 2 to a cell.

From this I want to get a percentage of how many times a person has or has not updated after completing a job

Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Column "D" for person name and "E" for database update then formula in "F" column will be 
=IF(AND(D3<>"",E3="yes"),1,2)

Hope I understood your requirement correctly.